# How do I split and join a file that contains both numbers and strings?

Tags: python, string, split

So for the following variable all I'm trying to do is replace the _ with ,:

Here is the code i'm trying:

```
Thefile= '''
"Name"_"Course"_"Grade" 
"Norman White"_"Room 8-84, KMEC"_100
"Betty White"_"Room 8-85, KMEC"_98
"Student1"_"43 West Street, NYC"_95
"Student2"_"28 Mainstreet, Hoboken NJ"_93
"Student99"_"99 2nd. Ave., NYC"_85 '''

print(Thefile)
thefile_split = Thefile.split
[str(i) for i in thefile_split]
s = ","
s = s.join(thefile_split)
print(s)`
```

in which I get the following error:

**TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable**

Do I need to format the variable first or is my code wrong?

Comment: `thefile_split = Thefile.split()` - _call_ the split method - dont assign it to a variable

Comment: You just need to call the split() function., `Thefile.split()` instead of `Thefile.split`

Comment: also fix the other errors. `[str(i) for i in thefile_split]` creates a new list by converting strings into strings and throw away the list aftewards - `s = s.join(thefile_split)` joints the different _lines_ buy , - it does not remove the `_` and replace it by `,` etc.

Comment: all you would need is `rp = Thefile.replace('_')` ...

Comment: try googling `python replace character in string site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to replace one character with another, you could simply use regular expressions to get the job done:

```
import re
Thefile= '''
"Name"_"Course"_"Grade" 
"Norman White"_"Room 8-84, KMEC"_100
"Betty White"_"Room 8-85, KMEC"_98
"Student1"_"43 West Street, NYC"_95
"Student2"_"28 Mainstreet, Hoboken NJ"_93
"Student99"_"99 2nd. Ave., NYC"_85 '''

result = re.sub('_', ',', Thefile)
print(result)
```

re.sub looks for a '_' in the whole string and replaces it with ','

**Output**

```
"Name","Course","Grade" 
"Norman White","Room 8-84, KMEC",100
"Betty White","Room 8-85, KMEC",98
"Student1","43 West Street, NYC",95
"Student2","28 Mainstreet, Hoboken NJ",93
"Student99","99 2nd. Ave., NYC",85
```